# IOS Sandbox Auto-Renewal Subscription

Tags: ios

I am using Sandbox environment for Auto-Renewal, but I want to test cancel subscription in setting->iTunes&App Store-> View AppleId-> Manage-> cancel subscription.

With my test appleId I am not be able to cancel the subscription.

Please suggest and If anyone have JSON of cancel subscription by user please Post the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we cannot cancel our subscription on sandbox environment, however it will renew 5 times with the interval of sandbox environment renewal period and after that apple will automatically cancel the subscription.

Comment: Can I use my real account to test also?

Comment: Would you please tell me How to?